# File downloading without file extension

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to download a file in asp.net using Response.Redirect,but it is downloading without any file extension.

On Download button click,I am getting Url from database.
My Url will be as below

```
//LaunchURL= http://localhost/Test/setup.exe?environment=local;

string LaunchURL = URLUtilities.getLocalURL(
                   this.launchPath, this.localURLParameter2, mUserName, useXferToken);

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LaunchURL))
{
    ShowErrorBox();
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect(LaunchURL);
}
```

Comment: Please add some sample code.

Comment: What do you mean without any format?

Comment: Yes,No format.for example if setup.exe is my file it is downloading as setup without format.

Comment: you mean "file extension" then (please edit question to correct this). Even if you add the file extension you will need to specify the content type if you want the browser to handle different types differently. [Good resource for content types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147.aspx)

Comment: So what happens when user gets "save as" box? Does it not include the file extension in that?

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried to set correct content-type in Your response headers? 
Example code is:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.exe"
```

Comment: tried the below code,still facing same            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=setup.exe");
            Response.ContentType="application/octet-stream"; 
            
            
            Response.Redirect(LaunchURL);